# Memory leak issue in CI mysql_result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I do not understand why I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 10747904) (tried to allocate 93 bytes) in /home/project/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 167
```

**phpinfo() details**

```
                localvalue mastervalue
memory_limit    4028M      4028M
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    p.*,l.*,u.*,ct.*,t.*,pc.*
FROM 
    tbl_Product AS p 
    JOIN tbl_DistributorLocationId AS l ON p.fk_LocationId = l.pk_DistributorLocationId 
    JOIN tbl_Manufacturer AS m ON p.fk_Manufacturer = m.pk_ManufacturerId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Color AS c ON p.fk_Colors = c.pk_ColorId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Texture AS t ON p.fk_Texture = t.pk_TextureId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductLine AS pl ON p.fk_ProductLine = pl.pk_ProductLineId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_States AS s ON l.fk_StateId = s.pk_StateId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Users AS u ON l.fk_UserId = u.pk_UserId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_UserType AS ut ON u.fk_UserTypeId = ut.pk_UserTypeId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductCategories AS pc ON p.fk_CategoryId = pc.pk_CategoryId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_CategoryType AS ct ON pc.fk_CategoryTypeId = ct.pk_CategoryTypeId 
where 
    1 = 1 
    AND p.boolean_status = 1 
ORDER BY 
    LOCATE('', varchar_Title), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ProductLineText), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ColorName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_TextureName), 
    LOCATE('', text_Description), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryTypeName)
```

**Result from phpmyadmin**

```
39706 total, Query took 1.2748 seconds.
```

Comment: I doubt it's a memory leak, typically when you run out of memory while trying to allocate a small amount indicates an infinite loop somewhere in your code..  Just because the db part ran out of memory doesn't mean that was where the actual problem is, for example you could be pulling the same record out a billion times.

Comment: You can't fetch the very big data on the query... use do while loop to fetch and clear the memory

Comment: We would really need to see more code to figure out what it is, @Sundar has a good point, but impossible to know without more information.  4GB is a good chunk of memory so it would take a lot of rows or rows with a large amount of data such as BLOB images to run out of memory.

Comment: plz edit question  with some code where you getting error

Comment: It seems your query is fetch more data than available space... better to use limit and offset in query

Comment: query is returning **39706 total, Query took 1.2748 seconds.**

Comment: Thanks all of you, it was silly mistake. that query is fetch all results from table and it was not necessary to fetch all columns from Table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of following :

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini

   memory_limit = 128M;
2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:

   php_value memory_limit 128M

Answer (score 0):

Fetch Only records that you need in you application not all fetch all data from Tables.

**Before**

```
SELECT 
    p.*,l.*,u.*,ct.*,t.*,pc.*
FROM 
    tbl_Product AS p 
    JOIN tbl_DistributorLocationId AS l ON p.fk_LocationId = l.pk_DistributorLocationId 
    JOIN tbl_Manufacturer AS m ON p.fk_Manufacturer = m.pk_ManufacturerId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Color AS c ON p.fk_Colors = c.pk_ColorId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Texture AS t ON p.fk_Texture = t.pk_TextureId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductLine AS pl ON p.fk_ProductLine = pl.pk_ProductLineId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_States AS s ON l.fk_StateId = s.pk_StateId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Users AS u ON l.fk_UserId = u.pk_UserId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_UserType AS ut ON u.fk_UserTypeId = ut.pk_UserTypeId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductCategories AS pc ON p.fk_CategoryId = pc.pk_CategoryId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_CategoryType AS ct ON pc.fk_CategoryTypeId = ct.pk_CategoryTypeId 
where 
    1 = 1 
    AND p.boolean_status = 1 
ORDER BY 
    LOCATE('', varchar_Title), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ProductLineText), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ColorName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_TextureName), 
    LOCATE('', text_Description), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryTypeName)
```

**After**

```
SELECT 
    pc.pk_CategoryId, 
    pc.varchar_CategoryName, 
    c.pk_ColorId, 
    c.varchar_ColorName, 
    m.varchar_Title, 
    m.pk_ManufacturerId, 
    u.varchar_CompanyName, 
    u.pk_UserId, 
    pl.pk_ProductLineId, 
    pl.varchar_ProductLineText
FROM 
    tbl_Product AS p 
    JOIN tbl_DistributorLocationId AS l ON p.fk_LocationId = l.pk_DistributorLocationId 
    JOIN tbl_Manufacturer AS m ON p.fk_Manufacturer = m.pk_ManufacturerId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Color AS c ON p.fk_Colors = c.pk_ColorId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Texture AS t ON p.fk_Texture = t.pk_TextureId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductLine AS pl ON p.fk_ProductLine = pl.pk_ProductLineId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_States AS s ON l.fk_StateId = s.pk_StateId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Users AS u ON l.fk_UserId = u.pk_UserId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_UserType AS ut ON u.fk_UserTypeId = ut.pk_UserTypeId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ProductCategories AS pc ON p.fk_CategoryId = pc.pk_CategoryId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_CategoryType AS ct ON pc.fk_CategoryTypeId = ct.pk_CategoryTypeId 
where 
    1 = 1 
    AND p.boolean_status = 1 
ORDER BY 
    LOCATE('', varchar_Title), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ProductLineText), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_ColorName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_TextureName), 
    LOCATE('', text_Description), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryName), 
    LOCATE('', varchar_CategoryTypeName)
```

Comment: apply limit and run batch process.., if it's a report give limited amount or give a summary of informations..

Comment: i need all data as same time so limit is not possible in this particulate application